# Python Requests Library and Lists

Tags: python, list, python-requests

I am having a problem using the Python Requests library to call a RESTful web service with Lists.

I am creating a Python object from data that includes Set objects, but I am turning them into Lists, which works fine (please note the constant data is only for testing purposes, this data will be coming in from a file):

```
  countriesSet = set(["US", "DE"])
  categoriesSet = set(["CAT1"])
  body = {
    "countries": list(countriesSet),
    "categories": list(categoriesSet),
    ...
  }
  logging.debug("%s: body = %r" % (FUNCTION_NAME, body))
  try:
    callAddUpdateFavDestSvc(body)
```

The log:

```
body = {... 'countries': ['US', 'DE'], 'categories': ['CAT1'], ...}
```

I then call `requests.request` with the `body` field from above:

```
response = requests.request(method, url, params = params, data = body)
```

However, when I look at the request object in my microservice (`Node.js` using `restify`, I end up "losing" the list for any lists that only have one entry - it ends up as a string instead:

```
...,"countries":["US","DE"],"categories":"CAT1",...
```

I believe the problem is with the data that `requests.request()` is sending, and not restify on the receiving end, because I can pass in single element lists successfully with Postman and curl with no problems in our microservice.

How do I get `requests.request()` to stop turning my single-entry list into a string?

Comment: just perform `json.loads()` on the decoded result.

Comment: Try `json = body` instead of `data`

Comment: Using `json = body` resolved the issue. Thanks!